# contacts sync with my own application like skype or whatsapp

Tags: java, android, synchronization

Iam making an android application similar to skype what i want to know is how to synchronize android contacts with my application so that the numbers which are registered with my application and are also in my android contacts got a symbol. For example in your contact list you see a skype icon or whatsapp icon with those contacts who are registered with skype or whats app.Anyone can guide me what to do.thanks!

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Please refer to the android.provider.`ContactsContract class`. Since it is very broad, I recommend you to first take a look at the SDK description of ContactsContract.RawContact. There you will find description with code snippets for basic operation on Contacts.

**Also, take a look at the Android SDK code examples:**

[Android Sample - ContactOperations](https://github.com/flyskywhy/android-sdk/blob/master/samples/android-8/SampleSyncAdapter/src/com/example/android/samplesync/platform/ContactOperations.java)

Comment: could you specify any tutorials?