# Contacts Sync in my Application

Tags: android, synchronization, odoo, odoo-mobile

I want to sync contacts from OpenERP server.
I have followed all the links. 
My account is also added but my contacts are not added under my account.

Group is also created of my account but there are no contacts in that account.

I have followed all this links but nothing is working.

[contacts sync with my own application like skype or whatsapp](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11622909/contacts-sync-with-my-own-application-like-skype-or-whatsapp)

[Android contact programmed sync](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3370544/android-contact-programmed-sync)

Answer (score 0):

There are already official app for that

### [OpenERP Mobile](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.openerp)

or you can develop your own.

### [OpenERP Mobile Framework Doc](http://odoo-mobile-doc-v2.readthedocs.org/en/latest/)

Thanks

Comment: But if you are developer then you can develop your own app. on that documentation they also given example App for CRM Lead :)

Comment: So may be you can start developing app with that framework :P because it has lot's of advantage Like
you does not need to develop login, menus, sync service etc  
it is exactly like openerp WEB framework. it has ORM so you does need to write query. And it also supports openerp methods like (create,read, write, unlike etc.)
and they already gave source code

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/51886/discussion-between-sweetwisher--and-parth-gajjar)

Comment: I knw its bit late to ask...but anyone can tell the steps to create a custom module in Android. I have module named Students, what should I do first..??

Comment: @ParthGajjar Is there any way to create new model without declare all the fields in Model class, bcz i am working on large scale of fields like order, order line etc.